# using SpringEL expression inside thymeleaf sec:authorize tag

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

when I try use a tag like that in my thymeleaf view:

```
sec:authorize="hasPermission(#user, 'cadastrar-__${name}__')"
```

the value `cadastrar-__${name}__` is not being processed and it's passed to the processor as is.

I try this too:

```
sec:authorize="|hasPermission(#user, 'cadastrar-__${name}__')|"
```

but i got this error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1069E:(pos 0): missing expected character '|'
```

anyone know the right way to work with this kind of expression with the `sec:authorize` tag?

Comment: Does #user get resolved for you? My targetDomainObject #foo always resolves to null, no matter what I do.